# Java Seperaing Inputsteam And Outputsteam To Different Cmd Windows

Tags: java, input, cmd, io, output

I want to seperate my programs outputsteam to a cmd window inputsteam to another cmd window. I have tryed processbuilder and Runtime.exec but i couldnt do what i want. What is the way do that ?